# How do I find a RSS URL for a podcast in the Apple Podcasts directory?

Tags: podcasts, podcasts.app, rss

I have both a Mac (macOS Catalina) and an iPhone (iOS 13.5.1). When I find a podcast in the Apple Podcasts directory I'd like to be able to subscribe to that podcast in any RSS reader, which requires having the RSS URL. Since, not all "podcatchers" have complete/up-to-date directories, having the URL of the actual feed would make it easy to subscribe to any particular podcast.

Given that having an RSS feed is a requirement for a podcast being listed in the Apple Podcasts directory, there must be some way to find the RSS URL.